# grep command not reading comamnd output for this adb command

Tags: terminal, grep, adb, darwin, wc

On executing the following adb command with grep I get the following response in (darwin os) terminal. i count number of error after grep finds a "Error" string in response

```
adb -s derefedv645xxxxxx shell "am start -n com.samsung.networkui/.usa.EnhancedLteServices" | grep Error | wc -l
```

Output:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.samsung.networkui/com.samsung.networkui.usa.EnhancedLteServices} does not exist.
       0
```

Meaning there is no "Error" text in the response. why grep is not able to capture the text "Error" ? let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect stderr to stdout before using next comment. I would also suggest using `awk` to avoid 2 commands `grep + wc -l`:

```sh
adb -s derefedv645xxxxxx shell "am start -n com.samsung.networkui/.usa.EnhancedLteServices" 2>&1 | 
awk '/Error/ {++n} END {print n}'
```

Comment: @siva: Did this help you out?